# how to save a oracle form field values to a database table

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbmt_brg_agency_letters
    (ID,
     MTBRG_CREATE_DAT,
     MTBRG_ORNNN_ID,
     MTBRG_RATING_AGENCY_TXT,
     MTBRG_EXTRNL_LTR_RATING_TXT)
  VALUES
    ( MTBLR_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
     :VWMTBRG.CREATE_DAT,
     :VWMTBRG.ORNNN_ID,
     :VWMTBRG.RATING_AGENCY_TXT,
     :VWMTBRG.EXTERNAL_LETTER_RATING_TXT);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

when i tried to save form values to a table it not saving, I'm using **`WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED`** trigger.
I'm trying to insert one table values to  other table which are selected using a dropdowm in  a form.

Comment: At the first sight, code you posted looks OK. What happens when you push the button? Is there any message? If so, which one? Did you run the form in debug mode? What does debug say?

Comment: NO ERROR MESSAGE

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a new data block by using `Data Block Wizard` along with `tbmt_brg_agency_letters` to be the base table. This case, no need to write such an insert code.

Comment: Actually what i'm trying to do is -- there is another table buyer_ratings which displays records in form i.e of drop down type (values to drop down is from buyer_ratings table). if i select one value from dropdown and save the form the values should be saved to table tbmt_brg_agency_letters. @littlefoot

Comment: As I said, code you posted *looks OK*. Did you run form in debug mode?

Comment: yes, i did not get any erros